# How do I use multiple cores with MSYS2 and mingw32-make?

Tags: windows, makefile, msys

I've tried specifying the -j8 or -j 8 parameters but they appear to have no effect. How do I enable multiple core compiling with MSYS2 and mingw32-make on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using --jobs=8 appears to have done the trick!